# How to use ORKESerializer in my app?

Tags: ios, json, researchkit

I am working on developing my first ResearchKit App.  I have been watching [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/213/).  One of the techniques used that is going to be helpful for me is serializing the results of a survey to JSON.  The method used in the video is `ORKESerializer.JSONDataForObject(taskResult)`.  He explains that this is not a standard part of researchKit, but it was included in a test app, called ORKTest that is on GitHub.

I set up my taskViewController delegate just like he had it set on the video, like this:

```
extension ViewController : ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {

    func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) {
        switch reason {
        case .Completed:
            let taskResult = taskViewController.result

            let jsonData = try! ORKESerializer.JSONDataForObject(taskResult)
            if let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                print(jsonString)
            }
            break

        case .Failed, .Discarded, .Saved:
            break

        }
        //Handle results with taskViewController.result
//        let taskResult = taskViewController.result
        taskViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I am getting this error upon compiling : `use of unresolved identifier: ORKESerializer`

So in the ORKTest app, in the GitHub files, I found 2 files.  One called `ORKESerialization.h`, and one called `ORKESerialization.m`.  I tried dragging those into my project, as I saw those files in the man's project in the video. And then that also prompted me to create a bridging header file as well, which I also saw in his project.

[image: shows files included in my project]

After doing that I am still getting the same error.  The truth is I don't know exactly how to include these serialization packages with my app.  Does anyone know how to included the right files so that I can implement this ORKEserialization method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import ORKESerialization.h in your bridging header:

```
  #import "ORKESerialization.h"
```

Comment: Hi, I just ran into an issue.  Your solution here worked for running my project in the simulator and printing JSON strings to the console output, but now I am getting 3 errors related to the `.m` file from this package when archiving the app for a generic iOS device.  errors:`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`, `  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKLocation", referenced from:`, `  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKConfirmTextAnswerFormat", referenced from:`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sorry, this is the full error: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKLocation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ORKESerialization.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKConfirmTextAnswerFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ORKESerialization.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`