# iOS build succeeds but fails to archive

Tags: ios, json, xcode, researchkit

I have been working on my first ResearchKit app.  Since the last time I created an archive, I have included a custom library for creating JSON strings.  [See my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225543/how-to-use-orkeserializer-in-my-app).

After importing the .h file in that bridging-header file, I was able to use the package.

The project was running fine in the simulator.  I even did a fresh clean and build for the "Generic iOS Device", and that completed with no errors.  When I went to archive the project, during the linking stage, I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKLocation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ORKESerialization.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ORKConfirmTextAnswerFormat", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ORKESerialization.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

My Xcode version is 7.1.1.  I have been searching around the web for possible answers.  Apparently it might have something to do with these architecture version, but I can't seen to pinpoint the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it work on device?

Comment: Well i was archiving it in order to export to a file, and load on a device.  Since the archive failed I haven't tried exporting.  Should I still try to export it and install on a device?

Comment: You don't have to export it. Just select your device and press the play button.

Comment: Sorry, it took a while to sort some things out.  Yes i was able to plug in my iphone and run it on the device.  It had a couple warnings but no errors and it ran successfully.  It ran just like it did on the simulator.  It still gives me the error in the question when I run try to archive...

Comment: How did you include the library in your project?

Comment: Well i dragged the ORKESerialization.h and ORKESerialization.m files into my project.  Xcode then created a Bridging-Header.h file, and in there i wrote one line `#import "ORKESerialization.h"`.  I was then able to use the serializer function that I needed.

Comment: Make sure you have `arm64` set to `Architectures` in your project, and also in the frameworks that you use. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107640/discussion-between-jeffery-the-wind-and-jelly).

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Did you find a solution? I ran into a similar issue.. App works find on Simulator but I am unable to archive it

Comment: @PersianBlue I'm sorry this was such a long time ago I don't remember, but yes I did eventually get past it. Wish I remember what happened. Only thing I can think of is make sure all your versions are correct for the researchkit you are using.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Thanks for the reply. Yes, I checked everything, it all seems fine. Not sure why it is still not working

Comment: @PersianBlue I don't think it was a bug but yes I'm sure they can help you on the GitHub thread. I think it was something very subtle that you have do when building the dependencies of the project. Anyways, I don't do much iOS work anymore so not very fresh in my mind. Good Luck!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I have posted for help on GitHub hope to find some solution soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug. Best bet is to file it on Github.

Comment: ORKLocation is exposed in ORKResult.h